# awk multiple matching patterns

Tags: awk

awk seems to match all the patterns matching an expression and executes the corresponding actions. Is there a precedence that can be associated ?

For eg. In the below, lines starting with # (comments) are matched by both patterns, and both actions are executed. I want commented lines to match only the first action.

```
/^#.*/  {
    // Action for lines starting with '#'
}


{
    // Action for other lines
}
```

Comment: Why don't use else statement ?

Comment: @Zulu: Because it is idiomatic in AWK to use actions outside a block and use `next` to skip subsequent blocks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to keep the code you already have mostly intact, you could just use the `awk` [next](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_77.html) statement. Once you encounter the `next` statement, `awk` skips processing the current record and goes to the next line.

So if you put `next` into the bottom your 1st block the 2nd block wouldn't be executed.

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply `if,else` :

```
awk '{ if ($0 ~ /^#/) 
           // Action for lines starting with '#'
       else
           // Action for other lines
      }'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your other option is to use the pattern negation operator, '!', for the "everything else" line, if your match options are binary:

```
/^#.*/ {
  // Action for lines starting with '#'
}

!/^#.*/ {
  // Action for other lines
}
```

Of course, your second pattern could also simply match everything that doesn't start with a hash, i.e. /^[^#].*/

But presumably, your example is a simplification. For complex regular expressions, crafting the exact inverse match could be impossible. The negation operator just makes it explicit and foolproof.

And, as you may already know, the ".*" part is unnecessary.